# Assigning property of ViewModel to property of another ViewModel in C# WPF desktop app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I'm developing a `C# WPF MVVM` app. I'm new to to `MVVM` and not using any toolkits/libraries, just an `ActionCommand` class which implements the `ICommand` interface and a `BaseINPC` class which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` (my ViewModels derive from this class).

My Model has a `DataSet` class with a string `InputPath` property (the location of the dataset file).

In my `MainView`, I have a `Menu` on the top which is a View of it's own (`MenuView`), implemented using a `UserControl` which has it's `DataContext` set to it's corresponding `MenuViewModel`. Each menu item is bound to an `ActionCommand` which does basic IO operations, such as `OpenFileDialogs` for loading files etc. The `MenuViewModel` has a `SelectedPath` property for holding the location of the file.

My problem is this: when I select a file using my `MenuView` (i.e. setting the `SelectedPath` property in my `MenuViewModel`), I also want it to set `DataSet.InputPath` to `SelectedPath`. My `DataSet` class is however instantiated in my `MainViewModel`, not the `MenuViewModel`, which is pretty much where I'm stuck.

Is my approach correct? If so, how can `DataSet.InputPath` (in `MainViewModel`) be set to `SelectedPath` (of `MenuViewModel`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on not using an MVVM framework you need to write your own Message Bus implementation...

Otherwise, virtually all MVVM frameworks use Message Bus for this type of inter-VM communication so picking a nice noob friendly MVVM framework (I'd recommend Simple MVVM Toolkit or MVVM Light) and utilizing its Message Bus instead of reinventing the wheel and writing your own MB is the way to go.

Comment: After the implementation of this feature you will be able to send a notification from one viewmodel to another. Read more details here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj694937.aspx).

Comment: @bogza.anton So you're encouraging him to write his own implementation of Message Bus instead of utilizing one of the well established, peer reviewed MVVM frameworks? If his goal is purely academic that would make sense otherwise my recommendation is to get a good MVVM framework and move on to writing the code that really matters...

Comment: i ended up with no frameworks since i thought they wouldn't be necessary, but since apparently they are needed i'll have to check out @DeanK.'s suggested frameworks.

Comment: @DeanK. extending my question based on your suggestion: assuming I was indeed using an MVVM framework, was the approach correct (viewmodels passing parameters to each other)?

Comment: @globetrotter Yes, in that scenario you would be using framework's SendMessage() method to pass an object between View Models...

Comment: @DeanK. in which case I'm marking your reply as answer, thanks.